# How to create tar with multiple file not directories

Tags: tar

How to create tar with multiple files from directory. 
But not directory itself only files from the directory into a single tar file.

Comment: What library are you using in delphi, or was the tag accidental added?

Comment: Sorry accidently added tag delphi-7, I  mean with tar.exe

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
tar -cf test.tar -C yourdir .
```

from tar man page:

```
-c, --create            create a new archive
-f, --file=ARCHIVE      use archive file or device ARCHIVE
-C, --directory=DIR     change to directory DIR

.                       every file in selected DIR
```

Comment: it does not create any tar file

Comment: It does on my machine. The tar is named `test.tar`. Please send me the command you tried, that did not create a tar file.

Comment: I have a folder where I have tar.exe as well a folder name files , when I execute tar -cf myfiles.tar -C files I get error tar: Cowardly refusing to create an ampty archieve.

Comment: Is your folder `files` empty? If so, tar is refusing to create an empty archive!

Comment: Also, you forgot the `.` after files.

Comment: Yes, that can not be changed. But this will still work with all extractors.

Comment: yes there are files in folder . when i use tar -cf myfiles.tar -C files . , then tar archieve is created but in tar archieve local disk icon and all files are with .\ , how to create an tar archieve same as files in folder, how to get only files in tar archieve without local disk and with out .\

Comment: The `.\` must be present. It does not work without. There is no way around this.